# STArray documentation for newbies and State/ST related questions

Tags: arrays, haskell, state, higher-rank-types

I have a hard time to understand `STArray` from the documentation and other howtos/discussion I've found through Google. I've got some more related questions below.

According to the documentation, `STArray`s are

> Mutable boxed and unboxed arrays in the ST monad.

This gave me the impression, that `STArray` is meant to be used as a *state* being passed around between functions (imagine you have a vector that has to be updated often).

Apparently this is used differently though:

```
ST s (STArray s a e)
```

What is the state `s` here? If it is used internally, then why is this not hidden from the user?

This also means, if we want to use a `STArray s Int Int` being passed around as state, one would define

```
type StateArray a = Control.Monad.State (ST s (STArray s Int Int)) a
```

which seems rather cumbersome.

Finally,

- what is the difference between `ST` and `State`?
- what is the difference between `STArray` and `IOArray`, if the `ST` and `IO` are meant for "internal" use?

Thank you!!

Comment: Usually Vectors are easier to use than arrays if you want to take a look at those.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

`ST` is a monad in which a limited type of side effects are allowed, namely mutable references and mutable arrays. Thus it allows you to implement functions which are pure as seen from the outside world, but which use mutation internally.

This is different from `State`, which only fakes mutation by threading the state through your computation as extra inputs and outputs. The difference is important when implementing some imperative algorithms, because they sometimes need mutation to be implemented efficiently. For example using a regular array in a `State` monad, you can only modify it by making a copy, whereas with `ST` you can have true mutation in-place.

The reason why we have both `ST` and `IO` is that `ST` provides stronger guarantees than `IO`, namely:

1. `ST` does not allow arbitrary side effects like for example accessing the file system.
2. We can guarantee that the side effects `ST` *does* allow cannot escape the scope of `runST`, and so it can be seen as pure from the outside world.

The reason why we can guarantee that the side effects cannot escape is related to the type variable `s`. Since any ST action must be polymorphic in `s`, you cannot write code which allows any mutable references to enter or leave the scope of a `runST`, because the type checker will complain that it cannot guarantee that the `s` of your action and that of the reference or array are the same *unless* they come from the same `runST` scope.

As an example of using the `ST` monad with mutable arrays, here is an implementation of the Sieve of Erathostenes:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Array.Unboxed

primesUpto :: Int -> [Int]
primesUpto n = [p | (p, True) <- assocs $ sieve n]

sieve :: Int -> UArray Int Bool
sieve n = runSTUArray $ do
    sieve <- newArray (2, n) True
    forM_ [2..n] $ \p -> do
        isPrime <- readArray sieve p
        when isPrime $ do
            forM_ [p*2, p*3 .. n] $ \k -> do
                writeArray sieve k False
    return sieve
```

<sub>`runSTUArray` is a specialized form of `runST` which allows you to build an array using mutation on the inside, before freezing it and returning it as an immutable array. `newArray`, `readArray` and `writeArray` do what you'd expect.</sub>

As you can see, the type signature of `sieve` indicates that it's a pure function, and it is. However, it uses mutation heavily on the inside to implement it efficiently.

Comment: Is there an equivalent of `runSTUarray` with vectors?

Comment: @justin I think create in Data.Vector.Unboxed is the equivalent of runSTUArray

Comment: I don't understand why there aren't any code examples on Hackage. It's very difficult, if not impossible, for someone who doesn't yet have a lot of experience in Haskell to understand how to use such non-trivial functions based solely on their types and some very formal definitions, without any examples.