# How does the ST monad work?

Tags: haskell, monads

I understand that the ST monad is something like a little brother of IO, which in turn is the state monad with added `RealWorld` magic. I can picture states and I can picture that RealWorld is somehow put into IO, but every time I write a type signature of `ST` the `s` of the ST monad confuses me.

Take, for example, `ST s (STArray s a b)`. How does the `s` work there? Is it just used to build up some artificial data dependency between computations without being able to be referenced like states in the state monad (due to the `forall`)?

I'm just throwing out ideas and would really appreciate someone more knowledgeable than I to explain it to me.

Comment: If you search for "ST monad", there's an entry that kind of answers my question as a side answer to a question about STArrays. Not sure if my question here's a duplicate now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197032/starray-documentation-for-newbies-and-state-st-related-questions

Comment: It's so tempting to simply answer "Yes." to your question. :)

Comment: I guess adding a link to the question and closing it would a) make searching for this easier in the future, and b) save some answerers some time.

Comment: I'll point you to [my writeup on rank-2 types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031878/what-is-the-purpose-of-rank2types/12033549#12033549), which should help you understand the `ST` monad as well.  Once you understand how rank-2 types can control "who chooses" the type used for a type variable, that should help you understand how `ST` operations use rank-2 to prevent its computations from being used illicitly.

Comment: You can write `a :: ST Int Int; a = return 2`  `ST` is a perfectly ordinary state monad, except it uses an unboxed pair as output of the state function `State# s -> (# State# s, a #)` which  makes it impractical to deal with.  The mystery is entirely in `runST` which has a rank 2 type, though ST itself isnt one.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The `s` keeps objects inside the `ST` monad from leaking to the outside of the `ST` monad.

```
-- This is an error... but let's pretend for a moment...
let a = runST $ newSTRef (15 :: Int)
    b = runST $ writeSTRef a 20
    c = runST $ readSTRef a
in b `seq` c
```

Okay, this is a type error (which is a good thing! we don't want `STRef` to leak outside the original computation!).  It's a type error because of the extra `s`.  Remember that `runST` has the signature:

```
runST :: (forall s . ST s a) -> a
```

This means that the `s` on the computation that you're running has to have no constraints on it.  So when you try to evaluate `a`:

```
a = runST (newSTRef (15 :: Int) :: forall s. ST s (STRef s Int))
```

The result would have type `STRef s Int`, which is wrong since the `s` has "escaped" outside of the `forall` in `runST`.  Type variables always have to appear on the inside of a `forall`, and Haskell allows implicit `forall` quantifiers everywhere.  There's simply no rule that allows you to to meaningfully figure out the return type of `a`.

**Another example with `forall`:** To clearly show why you can't allow things to escape a `forall`, here is a simpler example:

```
f :: (forall a. [a] -> b) -> Bool -> b
f g flag =
  if flag
  then g "abcd"
  else g [1,2]

> :t f length
f length :: Bool -> Int

> :t f id
-- error --
```

Of course `f id` is an error, since it would return either a list of `Char` or a list of `Int` depending on whether the boolean is true or false.  It's simply wrong, just like the example with `ST`.

**On the other hand,** if you didn't have the `s` type parameter then everything would type check just fine, even though the code is obviously pretty bogus.

**How ST actually works:** Implementation-wise, the `ST` monad is actually the same as the `IO` monad but with a slightly different interface.  When you use the `ST` monad you actually get `unsafePerformIO` or the equivalent, behind the scenes.  The reason you can do this safely is because of the type signature of all `ST`-related functions, especially the part with the `forall`.

Comment: Could you "break" the safety of ST by using `realWorld#` directly in client code, to  mimic `runSTRep` ? It's a bad idea of course, but I'm wondering what the protections are, besides `realworld#` being an obviously unsafe value to use in a program.
 http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-ST.html#runST

Comment: @misterbee [Yep](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST.html#v:stToIO), and it not even necessarily unsafe. Remember, `s` only exists at the type level.

Answer (score 29):

The `s` is just a hack that makes the type system stop you doing things which would be unsafe. It doesn't "do" anything at run-time; it just makes the type checker reject programs that do dubious things. (It is a so-called *phantom type*, a thing with only exists in the type checker's head, and doesn't affect anything at run-time.)

Answer (score 0):

> Take, for example, `ST s (STArray s a b)`: how does the `s` work there?

Time for a GHCi session:

```
GHCi, version 8.4.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> let _ = (\x -> x^4) 5 in x

<interactive>:2:27: error: Variable not in scope: x
Prelude>
```

The *scope* (or *frame of reference*) for the
*local variable* `x` is the lambda/anonymous function `\x -> x^4` - outside that scope, `x` is otherwise undefined, hence the error.

The type for `runST`:

```
runST :: (forall s . ST s a) -> a
```

works in similar fashion: the scope of the *locally-quantified* type-variable `s` is the type `ST s a` (the type of `runST`'s parameter) - if `s` appears in the type of the result, it too is outside its scope and also lacks a sensible definition, causing a type-error.

So if you:

- have an action `m :: ST s (STArray s a b)`
- and you inadvertently try to extract the
  mutable array from `m`:

  ```
    … (let arr = runST m in …) …
  ```

...the *escape* of `s` outside its scope:

```
forall s . ST s (STArray s a)
```

(and its detection by the type system) stops the [sharing of mutable state](https://mb21.github.io/blog/2021/01/23/pure-functional-programming-and-shared-mutable-state.html), a well-known source of elusive errors, particularly in the context of parallelism and concurrency.

Comment: So you mean that because runST extracts a from a ST s a and it happens that this a has an s in it (a is a STRef s a' ) it is why the compiler complains? Every where it is written that it's the rank2 polymorphism of runST which forbids to extract the a from a ST s a.

Comment: Not `runST`: it's the [extended] Haskell type system which detects the escape of the locally-quantified type-variable `s`, resulting in the error message.

Comment: The rankN explanation is more clear for me even if still very abstract... runST has to have the freedom to choose s but then it's given a locked representation and the compiler starts yelling this is my understanding of the ST.

Comment: Alright, try this: make up a mock `ST` module using `runST = undefined`, `newSTRef = undefined`, `readSTRef = undefined` (with the appropriate type declarations and signatures), then try sneaking a `STRef` out of (or into) a `runST` call...

Comment: probably your reasoning is similar to the one of the rankN one - I just don't saw this every explanation is going in the rank2 polymorphism, for instance I understand rank2 in situation when you give o polymorphic function and the implementation is able to choose/adapt the type but have problem to understand why it's restictring the function domain (for ex. @dfeuer response in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031878/what-is-the-purpose-of-rank2types/24717685?noredirect=1#comment121399355_24717685)

Comment: I agree with that suggestion by dfeuer: write up a new question which precisely describes what you would like to know or understand (alternately, what it is about higher-rank types that you're not sure about - provide examples.)