# When to use STRef or IORef?

Tags: haskell, ioref

What exactly is the difference between STRef and IORef and when do I use each of them? As far as I can tell they both are for mutable state so whats the point of both of them existing?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can do more things in the `IO` monad than in the `ST` monad. The latter provides mutable references, the former provides mutable references, exception catching, threads, and of course IO.

It is usually good Haskell practice to use the "weakest" or "more restricted" tool available that can solve your problem, because "weaker" tools tend to be easier to understand and analyze (another place this principle crops up in Haskell is in the `Applicative` versus `Monad` distinction).

So, if you *only* need mutable references, use `ST`. Future maintainers will be able to infer more about what your function does (and doesn't do) just by looking at the type.

An example situation in which you are forced to use `IORef`s (or their cousins `MVar`s) is when having to share a mutable reference between two different execution threads.

Also keep in mind that you can escape `ST` (which means you can run `ST` computations inside pure functions) but you can't escape `IO`.

Comment: The last point is, IMHO, the most important one: `ST` lets you safely use imperative features while providing a pure interface.

Comment: What exactly does ST computations inside pure function look like? Can you give an example of escape?

Comment: @user782220 You escape `ST` using the `runST` function. The Haskellwiki page on `ST` has some examples: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad/ST See also the `RankNTypes` extension: https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/guide-to-ghc-extensions/explicit-forall#use-case--the-st-monad

Comment: `ST` not only has mutable references, but also mutable arrays

Answer (score 10):

They each provide the same functionality, but for different monads.  Use `IORef` if you need a managed ref in `IO`, and `STRef` if you need one in `ST s`.

EDIT: a brief example:

```
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.IORef
import Data.STRef

exampleSTRef :: ST s Int
exampleSTRef = do
  counter <- newSTRef 0
  modifySTRef counter (+ 1)
  readSTRef counter

exampleIORef :: IO Int
exampleIORef = do
  counter <- newIORef 0
  modifyIORef counter (+ 1)
  putStrLn "im in ur IO monad so i can do I/O"
  readIORef counter
```

Comment: What's `s` in `exampleSTRef`?

Comment: @dimid Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12468757/1193741) for an explanation.