# Data.Vector, mapping with accumulator

Tags: haskell

I would like to do a map with an accumulator on Data.Vector.

I want to write the function inc:

```
inc :: Vector.Vector Bool -> Vector.Vector Bool
```

which "adds one" to the vector, e.g.:

```
inc <False, False, False> = <False, False, True>
inc <False, False, True> = <False, True, False>
inc <True, True, True> = <False, False, False>
```

If there was something like Data.List's mapAccumR, say with type:

```
mapAccumR :: (acc -> x -> (acc, y)) -> acc -> Vector x -> (acc, Vector y)
```

this could be done with

```
inc = snd . Vector.mapAccumR inc' True
  where
    inc' x y = (x && y, (x || y) && (not (x && y)))
```

but I can't figure it out how to do it with what is in Data.Vector.Unboxed. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to reverse your scheme and have the least significant bits on the front of the vector, like this:

```
inc <False, False, False> == <True, False, False>
```

The reason is that [`mapM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.12.2/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html#g:22) and [`unfoldr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.12.2/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html#g:10) are both suitable for defining `inc` with this bit ordering, but not with the other order, and there aren't reversed versions of these functions in `vector`. As an example, `mapM` lets us implement `inc` with the help of the State monad:

```
import Control.Monad.State
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V

inc :: V.Vector Bool -> V.Vector Bool
inc v = evalState (V.mapM go v) True where
  go acc = state $ \x -> (x /= acc, x && acc)
```

Alternatively, we could do two reversals to get back to the original ordering. That would be asymptotically the same, but practically significantly slower.

Of course, we can still do a lower-level implementation for `mapAccumR`. This necessitates working in the `ST` monad with mutable vectors, which isn't particularly hard, but it's not trivial either. There isn't a lot of material online on the ST monad; on Stack Overflow you may [benefit from reading this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468622/how-does-the-st-monad-work) and optionally following the links from there. I try to comment on the important parts in the `mapAccumR` implementation below.

```
-- we need this so we can annotate objects in the ST monad with
-- the right parameters
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Control.Monad.ST.Strict
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as MV

-- note that I explicitly introduce the type variables
-- with forall. This - in conjunction with ScopedTypeVariables - 
-- lets us refer to the type variables in the function body.
mapAccumR ::
  forall x y acc.
  (V.Unbox x, V.Unbox y) =>
  (acc -> x -> (acc, y)) -> acc -> V.Vector x -> (acc, V.Vector y)
mapAccumR f acc v = runST $ do
  let len = V.length v

  -- Allocate a mutable unboxed vector of v's size.
  -- We need to annotate the "s" parameter here, so we can
  -- refer to it in the type of "go".
  (mv :: MV.STVector s y) <- MV.unsafeNew len

  -- iterate through the new vector in reverse order,
  -- updating the elements according to mapAccumR's logic.
  let go :: Int -> acc -> ST s acc
      go i acc | i < 0 = return acc
      go i acc = do
        -- y comes from the old vector
        -- we can access it via the immutable API
        let (acc' , y) = f acc (V.unsafeIndex v i)
        -- but we must do mutable writes on the new vector
        MV.unsafeWrite mv i y
        go (i - 1) acc'

  acc' <- go (len - 1) acc

  -- "unsafeFreeze" converts the mutable vector to
  -- an immutable one in-place.
  v'   <- V.unsafeFreeze mv
  return (acc', v')
```

Comment: Thanks! I had the feeling that it should be doable with the monadic things, but couldn't piece it together, I have to read up on the state monad.

Comment: You probably should get down dirty with stream bundles if you really want to make a general purpose one.

Comment: That's right, but I'm not familiar with writing stream fusion code. At least the `mapM` solution is streaming, I believe. BTW the latest `vector` doesn't have stream bundles.