# Why is `forall` required to have a polymorphic type in data definition?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, parametric-polymorphism

It seems that I need to explicitly say `forall` to have a parametric type in data definition. For example, this

```
data A = A (forall s. ST s (STUArray s Int Int))
```

will work while this

```
data A = A (ST s (STUArray s Int Int))
```

won't.

Maybe I'm asking something too obvious, but the reason for this is not clear to me because in most other cases you don't need an explicit `forall` to specify a parametric type; the compiler does it instead. So what is the difference here?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468622/how-does-the-st-monad-work) answer

Comment: The compiler infers an implicit `forall` when it's a top-level declaration, but that's the only time.

Comment: Well, because if you write: `data A = A a` you could simply have forgotten to add the type parameter: `data A a = A a`. In fact I believe this is the most common case, so requiring an explicit `forall` removes the ambiguity and avoids bugs.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, also for class member declarations, GADT constructor declarations, and as a result of `let` generalization.

Comment: And `let` with an explicit signature, I should've said as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two different places the `forall` could go, only one of which is what you intend. The other is

```
data A = forall s . A (ST s (STUArray s Int Int))
```

Which is equivalent to the GADT syntax

```
data A where
  A :: ST s (STUArray s Int Int) -> A
```

This can be thought of as a box holding an `ST` state transformer with some `s` or other—completely useless. But the type checker isn't specially tailored to the needs of `ST`, and similar types are useful in other contexts.