# Getting every Friday until a certain date, but in a functional style?

Tags: javascript, haskell, functional-programming, underscore.js, lazy-evaluation

For example, I want to get the dates of every Friday from now until 30 days from now.

Currently, I can make use of the underscore library and moment.js to do this. But the result is super verbose and annoyingly procedural/imperative. Observe:

```
var initDate = moment().day("Friday");
var endDate = moment().add(30, 'days');

var result = [];
result.push(initDate);

while (_.last(result).isBefore(endDate)) {
    var x = _.last(result);
    result.push(nextWeek(x));
}

alert(result);    // answer here

// create a new moment from given moment and add 7 days
function nextWeek(initMoment) {
    var x = moment(initMoment);
    return x.add(7,'days');    
}
```

Here is the corresponding fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aafsh5xa/

I was wondering if there's a way to use Haskell-like features such as list comprehensions or infinite lists (lazy evaluation) to make this a lot more concise. Maybe something like:

```
var initDate = moment();
var endDate = moment().add(30,days);

var everyFriday = genLazyList(initDate, nextFridayFrom);
var result = _.filter(everyFriday, function(input){ return input.isBefore(endDate); });
```

Note that everyFriday is an infinite list generated by genLazyList and is not evaluated until the _.filter() function is called upon it. And nextFridayFrom() is a function that genLazyList uses to make the lazy list.

Comment: maybe it's just me, but shouldn't this be rather simple -> **http://jsfiddle.net/aafsh5xa/1/**

Comment: I am asking specifically about using functional programming techniques to accomplish it. Your fiddle and my fiddle is just as non-functional.

Comment: In short, no there's no way to do that in JS, `genLazyList` would be executed and evaluated when called, and return every friday from now until eternity, there's no way to delay evaluating it until it's in ran through a filter.

Comment: I found a way to do it with this library: http://streamjs.org/

Give me some time and I'll write an answer that'll do what I suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note I am using [stream.js](http://streamjs.org/) and [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) in my answer. So you'll have to do the following includes in your HTML (note that my syntax is in jade):

```
script(src="path/to/stream.js")
script(src="path/to/moment.js")
```

And here is my code:

```
var initDate = moment().day("Friday");
var endDate = moment().add(30,'days');

function allFridays() {
    return new Stream(initDate, function(){
            return allFridays().map(function(date){return moment(date).add(7,'days')});
        }
    );    
}

allFridays().takeWhile(function(h){return h.isBefore(endDate)}).print();
```

Or in my favourite flavour, coffeescript:

```
initDate = moment().day('Friday')
endDate = moment().add(30, 'days')

allFridays = ->
  new Stream(initDate, ->
    allFridays().map (date) ->
      moment(date).add 7, 'days'
)

allFridays().takeWhile((h) -> h.isBefore endDate).print()
```

Isn't that just beautiful?

A quick explanation:

1. I make an infinite stream of moment (date) objects which represent all fridays from now until forever
2. I take (i.e. retrieve) the elements of this stream up until the first moment which does not represent a time before my endDate.

And that's it!

Note that the `takeWhile()` function is not yet implemented in the official stream.js release, but I simply copy and pasted it in from its lib folder. See its git repo [here](https://github.com/dionyziz/stream.js).

Comment: Neat. Here's my take on it (using stream.js), without `moment.js` and generic for all weekdays: http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/0L02La7v/

Comment: nice! Some useful ideas there, @KooiInc.

Answer (score 2):

Does JS have a Julian date library? That would make things a lot simpler.

Here is some pseudo-Haskell code assuming that we have the following functions:

```
toJulianDate :: Date -> Int
toDate :: Int -> Date
dayOfWeek :: Date -> Int     -- 0 = Sun, 1 = Mon, ... 5 = Fri, etc.
```

Then we can write:

```
everyFridayBetween :: Date -> Date -> [Date]
everyDridayBetween d1 d2 = map toDate [jfriday, jfriday+7..j2]
  where
    j1 = toJulianDate d1
    j2 = toJulianDate d2
    dow = dayOfWeek d1
    jfriday = if dow <= 5 then j1+(5-dow) else j1 + 7 + (5-dow)
```

Comment: This is quite an interesting way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if there's a way to use Haskell-like features such as list comprehensions or infinite lists (lazy evaluation) to make this a lot more concise.

In ES6, you'll be able to use a generator function ([spec](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-generator-function-definitions), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)) for the infinite list.

In the meantime, loops in functional programming are usually accomplished via recursion, right? So:

```js
function getFridays(f, dt, days) {
  if (days > 0) {
    if (dt.getDay() === 5) {
      f.push(new Date(dt));
    }
    dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
    f = getFridays(f, dt, days - 1);
  }
  return f;
}

var fridays = getFridays([], new Date(), 30);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(fridays, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

That version has side-effects, though (two of its arguments are objects whose state is mutated within the function). I'm not well-versed in functional programming, but I understand side-effects are to be avoided, so perhaps:

```js
function getFridays(date, days) {
  var f, newDate;
  
  f = [];
  if (days > 0) {
    if (date.getDay() === 5) {
      f.push(new Date(date));
    }
    newDate = new Date(date);
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
    return f.concat(getFridays(newDate, days - 1));
  }
  return f;
}

var fridays = getFridays(new Date(), 30);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(fridays, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

That's obviously a lot less memory-efficient (in terms of GC churn), but if I understand correctly, having no side-effects is more important in FP than memory/GC efficiency.

Comment: Just to note... You can mutate state even in a language like Haskell. The important consideration is whether the state being mutated is not visible outside of the function's scope, thus preserving referential transparency. See this answer about the ST Monad which allows us to mutate state while  statically guaranteeing this property. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8197275/536017

Comment: @danem: Right. That's why I posted the second example: The mutations caused by the first example would both be visible outside the function, e.g., side-effects.

Comment: Sure, but my point was, with that in mind, more efficient implementations are possible. Like this for instance: http://jsfiddle.net/6wsa0usq/1/. Which is just your first example implemented as a closure. Taken further, we have a valid example that is almost identical to an imperative implementation posted further up thread. http://lpaste.net/121435 All I was trying to say was that you needn't have to resort to recursion or any of that to get the benefits of FP. : )

Comment: @danem: My first example isn't "implemented as a closure" (in any way other than that **all** JavaScript functions are closures). It's just a recursive function. Re recursion: I thought that was how you did loops in FP. Do you do just normal loops in FP, then?

Comment: No, I never said your first example was implemented as a closure. I said the example I posted (http://jsfiddle.net/6wsa0usq/1/) was essentially your first example, but with the work being done in a closure, mutating the state in a "side-effect-free" way. And sorry, I should've said "explicit recursion". My point was that by using functions like "forM" (which is indeed defined recursively) we can in some cases write the same code you would with an imperative language. I was just trying to point out that recursion for its own sake isn't necessarily desirable.

Comment: @danem: Sorry, misread the closure comment. Re recursion: But again, isn't that how you do loops in FP? I could have introduced some library to do it, but there was no need (or so I thought; the OP decided to).

Answer (score 0):

Some proof of concept with **ES6 generator** functionality

```js
function *fridays13th() {
  var nextFriday = getNextFriday(new Date())

  while (true) {
    if (isFriday13th(nextFriday)) {
      yield new Date(nextFriday)
    }

    nextFriday = getNextFriday(nextFriday)
  }

  function isFriday13th(day) {
    return ((day.getDay() === 5) && (day.getDate() === 13))
  }

  function getNextFriday(d) {
    return new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() + (5 - d.getDay() > 0 ? 5 - d.getDay() : 12 - d.getDay())))
  }
}


function generator(fn) {
  var res = []
  var g = fn()

  return {
    take: function(max) {
      for (var i = 0; i < max; i += 1) {
        var r = g.next()
        res.push(r.value)
      }
      return res
    }
  }
}


var fridays = generator(fridays13th).take(5)


document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(fridays, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```